# Discord Python Bot not sending responses to commands

Tags: python, discord, bots

We are creating an Discord bot.

The Problem is that no error is in Console but the Chat in Discord is also empty. So no response at all. Could you please help me and say what my error is and how to resolve the problem

Best Wishes,
Niktix

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

import askai

import numpy
import random
import json
import datetime as DT
from time import sleep
import sLOUT as lout
import os

botStartTime = DT.datetime.now()
ver = ['v1.0.8', '2021-01-13']
config = 'config.yml'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
lout.writeFile('AskAIBotLogs.txt', '\naskai initialisiert!', True)
load_dotenv()


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def time(ctx):
    startTime = DT.datetime.now()
    await ctx.send('Auf dem server ist aktuell folgende Uhrzeit: {}'.format(DT.datetime.now()))
    lout.log(config, startTime, 'time')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=1, name='Beantwortet Fragen', url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3tuUKGIaGw', platform='YouTube', assets='askai',))
  lout.log(config, botStartTime, None, None, True)
  print('Eingeloggt als {}'.format(bot.user.name))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

  if message.author.bot:
    return
  if message.channel.name != "askai-support":
    return
  if message.content.startswith("!"):
    return

  await bot.process_commands(message)
  await message.channel.send(askai.ask(message.content))


bot.run('token')
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, does the bot not respond to anything? Try print debugging. i.e add print statements and see if the code is being executed properly or not

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it not work? Well, the answer is fairly simple. Please refer to the following lines you provided:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

  if message.author.bot:
    return
  if message.channel.name != "askai-support":
    return
```

> At this point in the code, you provide the channel name. Although, you don't provide the channel ID afterward. Therefore the bot cannot get said channel. In order to get the channel ID, please refer to Discord's official guide [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-#:%7E:text=On%20Android%20press%20and%20hold,ID%20to%20get%20the%20ID.). Upon doing that, make the same line of code as above, although replace "message.channel.name" with "message.channel.ID". Let me know if you have any further questions. Best Regards,

Comment: That is not a problem, we can recognise a channel from its name as well as id, id is preferred when we want to recognise a unique channel, since name might be repetitive, which is not the case with the OP

Comment: @Ceres Although this is the general thought of the masses, discord's official guide on how to set up bots says to include the channel name and ID. Thank you.